# Console <init> error

Tags: java, console

When I run my code it's coming up with an error in console.

```
"at com.tutorial.main.Game.<init>(Game.java:12)
    at com.tutorial.main.Window.<init>(Window.java:21)"
```

Code:

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!");
  }

  public synchronized void start() {

  }
  public void run() {

  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

This is the second file apparently they both are broken somehow?

```
package com.tutorial.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

  public Window(int width, int height, String title) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Game game = new Game();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();

  }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: in game class constructor you create new `window ` in  window class you create a new `game` ...so this is infinite process and give you stackoverflow error

Comment: I'm confused what do I have to delete I've already tried deleting a couple of line @FastSnail

Comment: you have to rethink of your programe flow . you have extend both game and window class with canvas ... remove line `new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!"); ` from game class /and add it to main method .also remove   ` new Game();` from main method of game class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `new window()` from constructor of game class.

remove `new game();` from main method.

add `new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!");` to main method

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

    public Game() {
       // removed line new window()
    }

    public synchronized void start() {

    }

    public void run() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
       // removed line new game()
       new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!"); // added this line here
    }
}
```

note

don't extend Window class with canvas.it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

new `Game()` calls `new Window()` which calls new `Game()` which calls new `Window()` etc.etc.etc. - this is the code that never stops.

The first line of the error should probably tell you that it's a "Stack Overflow".

Comment: I'm confused what do I have to delete I've already tried deleting a couple of line @Florian

Comment: Only you can decide that. You must decide if you either start by creating a new Game which then creates a new Window OR if you create a new Window which then creates a new Game. Both is simply an infinite loop. As we don't know your game, we cannot know that. Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game)
```

instead of

```
 Window(int width, int height, String title)
```

use

```
 new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!",this);
```

passing current class object `(this)`. So no need of creating `Game` class object again

instead of

```
new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!");
```

and one more, again you are creating `Game` class object in `Window` class its needed.

```
  Game game = new Game();
```

Window.java

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Window extends Canvas {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -240840600533728354L;

  public Window(int width, int height, String title, Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //Game game = new Game();//you are again creating Game class object here it gives you an error.
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();

  }

}
```

Game.java

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7580815534084638412L;

  public static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;

  public Game() {
    new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Lets Build a Game!",this);//passing current class object 
  }

  public synchronized void start() {

  }
  public void run() {

  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

Comment: but if I remove 'Game game = new Game();'
it will come up with an error